# Vaadin failed to load default widgetset

Tags: gradle, vaadin, gradle-plugin, vaadin8

I am using Vaadin 8 with Gradle for developtment of an application. When I try to run the application using vaadinRun from the Vaadin plugin for Gradle I get the following error:

```
Failed to load the widgetset: ./VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetset/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js
```

At the same time the console tells me the following:

```
INFORMATION: Requested resource [/VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
```

Did anyone have a similar problem and can tell me how to sove it, please?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Have you compiled the widgetset?

Comment: Yes, I compiled it.

Comment: Where is your widgetset located in the project?

Comment: And are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for your help. Somehow I had to explicitly include the dependency vaadin-client-compiled in my build.gradle. For everyone else in the group it worked fine without it.